# url naming issue in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I am trying to pass a parameter through states by `$stateProvider` and having a display issue. The parameter I try to pass is something like `"foo/bar/zoo"`, which means it contains `/` character.

In the URL, it looks as this: `*/foo%252Fbar%252Fzoo`.

Also, the controller seems to be loaded twice, because when I put `console.log(path);` in the Controller, it prints the output twice. First is the original value and second is the encoded version looks like `foo%2Fbar%2Fzoo`.

**The question is**, how can I pass a parameter containing `/`, and how can I block controller to be loaded twice?

state provider:

```
$stateProvider
    ...
    .state('app.group.wiki.pages', {
        url         : "/pages/{path:.*}",
        templateUrl : "modules/group/wiki/pages.html"
    })
```

Comment: Did you try using single quotes?

Comment: Yes, still the same issue.

Comment: can you please provide a full example? It's hard to guess what is the issue without having the full code example.